# NextAuth confirm with user before account creation

Tags: javascript, next.js, next-auth

Is there any way to confirm with the user before registration with next-auth? Automatically registering user is a terrible idea and there doesn't seem to be a good way to avoid it here.

I have tried to send whether the auth method is signup or login via query param but this just gets lost and isn't accessible in the the `signUp()` callback.

```
signIn("google", undefined, { authMethod: "signin" })
```

then in route

```
async function handler(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
  return await NextAuth(req, res, {
    callbacks: {
      session: ({ session, user }) => ({
        ...session,
        user: {
          ...session.user,
          id: user.id,
        },
      }),
      signIn: () => {
        // can't get the param here
        console.log( "Search Params", (req as unknown as NextRequest).nextUrl.searchParams.get("authmethod") as any);
        return true;
      },
    },
    adapter: PrismaAdapter(prisma),
    providers: [
      GoogleProvider({
        clientId: env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
        clientSecret: env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
      }),
    ],
  });
}
```

I don't see any way to set up a custom slug for the nextauth catchall so something like `/api/auth/[authmethod]/[...nextauth]/route.js`. And then just calling it directly but I just get an error `Error: This action with HTTP GET is not supported by NextAuth.js`.

There doesn't seem to be any way to pass data through the oauth state because Next Auth just hijacks this for their csrf token and doesn't seem to have any mechanism for using any custom data. They could just `JSON.strigify` any data that you want to pass along with their token but it doesn't seem that they have set up any way of actually doing that.

**My solution so far.**

The only solution I have found is to set a cookie on the browser side and check it on the server side. This seems like a hacky solution but I can do something like so:

```
function handleSignIn(type: string) {
  document.cookie = `next-auth.authentication-type=${type}`;
  signIn();
}
```

and then I can just get the cookie in the route.

```
const { value } = (req as unknown as NextRequest).cookies.get(
  "next-auth.authentication-type"
) as { name: string; value: string };

if(value === 'signup'){
    const dbUser = db.query('My db users query')
    if(!dbUser) return false
}
```

I don't really like it but that seems to be the solution so far.

**Small rant feel free to ignore:** I still can't believe they think automatically signing up users is a good idea. If you do this you have users who can't remember which email they signed up with being automatically signed up with a new account. This leads to dead users in your database and users who have 2 accounts with completely separate data. This is a terrible user experience and incredibly invasive.

Anyway does anyone have any insight on how this would be possible with Next Auth or is this just a lost cause?